# Select columns where isnull() is false

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works when I run it through my MySQL manager directly, however the query doesn't seem to work in my application.

I've identified the problem to be the following query:

```
SELECT task_id, member_id, SUM(NOT(ISNULL(completion_date))) AS complete, COUNT(id) AS total
FROM classroom_task_data
GROUP BY task_id, member_id
```

and specifically the `SUM(NOT(ISNULL(completion_date)))`.

If I change it to `SUM(ISNULL(completion_date))` (removed the `NOT`) the query works in my application. I don't know why this happens, but I figured I might as well try a different approach to get the result I want.

I tried `SUM(NOT ISNULL(completion_date))` as well, but without success. I also tested out `COALESCE` but I couldn't get it to work.

So I'm wondering how I can write the above differently but still get the same results.

Here's the full query btw:

```
SELECT id, title, member_id, instruction, start_date, end_date, is_archived, is_published, classroom_id, user_id 
FROM (
   SELECT task_id, member_id, SUM(NOT(ISNULL(completion_date))) AS complete, COUNT(id) AS total
   FROM classroom_task_data GROUP BY task_id, member_id
)
AS td 
JOIN
classroom_tasks AS t ON td.task_id = t.id
WHERE complete = total AND classroom_id = 35;
```

Comment: Whoever set this question to close obviously doesn't understand my question. I'm not asking why this code doesn't work **but if there's alternative to writing `NOT ISNULL()`**....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if statement would give the same result.

-0 when the completion_date is null

-1 when the completion_date is NOT null

```
SUM( if(completion_date IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS complete
```

Maybe you could try that

Answer (score 0):

Try IS NOT NULL:

```
SUM( completion_date IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: What did not work? Syntax error? incorrect result? or what? How is your table structure? Maybe completion_date definition is set to NOT NULL?

Answer (score 0):

This will sum completion_date if they are not null or otherwise add it with zero.

```
COALESCE(SUM(completion_date),0)
```